# What variables I can place in a Putty Link?

Tags: windows-7, terminal, putty

I create a new link in Windows with the following target:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh username -pw password
```

Are there any other options I can add in that one link target? I am interested to know if I can open a supporting program when this one is opens, or if i can navigate or set a variable after login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storing your password in plain text like that is not ideal. I'd suggest using shared keys instead.
However, if you want to do multiple things at once, a script really is the way to go rather than using a single shortcut to launch multiple things.

For example, using a vbs script, I can launch putty and internet explorer with a single action:

```
Dim ShellRun
Set ShellRun = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ShellRun.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe"" -ssh username@xx.xx.xx.xx -pw password", 1
ShellRun.Run "iexplore.exe"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of creating a batch file for that, but i was wondering what else can do in that link address.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only variables you can use in a shortcut are environment variables and I don't think you can use it to run multiple lines of commands. In testing, it seems to want to use additional portions as arguments rather than executing them separately.